# convert array to save in mysql nodejs

Tags: javascript

I have a read file script, the data is for example

kevin, smith, 321, street34

lady, sevilla, 4564, blv 34

carl, max, 1212, st 34#3

```
newDataArray = []

const data = fs.readFileSync('/Users/myuser/Documents/test.txt', 'utf8')

//here I delete  \n
let response = data.split(/\r?\n/g)


    //the array is now lenght 3

    response.forEach(element => {
        newDataArray.push(element)   
    });
```

but i need at the final the following

```
    {
      name: 'kevin',
      lastname: 'smith',
      phone: '321',
      add: 'street34' 
    },
    {
      name: 'lady',
      lastname: 'sevilla',
      phone: '4564',
      add: 'blv 34' 
    },
    {
      name: 'carl',
      lastname: 'max',
      phone: '1212',
      add: 'st 34#3' 
    }
```

and after may to save in mysql

```
//i dont know how to replace req.body

const { name, lastname, phone, add } = req.body;
    connection.query('INSERT INTO test_table SET ? ',
      {
        name,
        lastname,
        phone,
        add
      }
    , (err, result) => {
      res.redirect('/');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As simple as that:

```
let response = data.split(/\r?\n/g)
    .map( row => {
        row = row.split(', ');
        return {
            name: row[0],
            lastname: row[1],
            phone: row[2],
            add: row[3],
        }
    })
```

Comment: You could even do: `let response = data.split(/\r?\n/g)
    .map( row => {
        [ name, lastName, phone, row ] = row.split(', ');
        return {
            name,
            lastName,
            phone,
            add,
        }
    })`